# How to create scheduled task disconnect remote session

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to create a scheduled task without using the Windows interface (`taskschd.msc`).

The task in question is the one listed in the interface as: *When disconnecting from a user session*. With the options:

- Any user
- Connection from a remote computer.

I have tried using the `schtasks /create /sc ONEVENT`... option, however, I can't find the right event ID.

I have reviewed the following documentation but I am unable to emulate the behavior of the task created from the interface .

https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-logon-types.html

https://andreafortuna.org/2020/06/04/windows-forensic-analysis-some-thoughts-on-rdp-related-event-ids/#sessiondisconnected

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/advanced-security-auditing

https://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/kb/windows-event-log-id-list.html?tab=Logon/logoff

Would anyone know how to emulate it to create the task via batch?

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: Event ID 4634, 4624, 24, 39 & 40. It is executed when establishing the remote connection and when disconnecting it. What I'm looking for is that it only runs when the remote session is disconnected.